# Magento add category select tab to custom plugin

Tags: magento

I am using the Inchoo Custom Designed Gallery Plugin: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-custom-designed-gallery/ . This plugin creates a gallery and a name could be given to the gallery.

Though I would like to link the plugin to a category selector (in a tab-form). So that the gallery is linked to a category.

What I already tried is adding the following to app/code/local/Inchoo/Cpa/Block/Cat/Edit/Tabs.php:

```
$this->addTab('categories', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Categories'),
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/categories', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));
```

It doesn't have any effect. What can I do? I'm quite new in Magento Extension Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Unfortunately not in the form of a tab, but I found a way to link to the categories.

Go to app/code/local/Inchoo/Cpa/Block/Cat/Edit/Tab/Info.php and add after the addfield functions a new function:

```
    $fieldset->addField('cat_select', 'select', array(
      'label'     => 'Category',
      'class'     => 'required-entry',
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'cat_select',
      'values' => $this->get_categories(),
      'disabled' => false,
      'readonly' => false,
      'tabindex' => 1
    ));
```

Add the following function to select categories:

```
protected function get_categories(){

    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
    $tree = $category->getTreeModel(); 
    $tree->load();
    $ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds(); 
    $arr = array();
    if ($ids){ 
    foreach ($ids as $id){ 
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
    $cat->load($id);
    $arr[$id] = $cat->getName();
    } 
    }

    return $arr;

}
```